# GDAL library orginfo -spat option

Tags: libraries, gdal

Has anyone used the ogrinfo [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] option in the GDAL tools? I am able to run the - sql query on the shape files and get the answers/shapes but however if I use the lat/long values in spat, I dont get the results (However I dont get an error). I could not find an example at all.

Comment: It would be useful if you can post the command with exact arguments you are executing

Answer (score 2):

This suggests one of three options:

1. Your file is not georeferenced as you expect
2. Your area of interest extent values are entered incorrectly
3. There are no features that both match your sql query AND lie within the extent as you have defined it.

You can test your understanding of the -spat values by creating a polygon to match and overlaying it in (say) QGIS to see how it overlaps with your data.  This will quickly help you eliminate the options above.  After that - you'll understand the feature for future use :)